# Show week number in Datebox Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, datebox

I'm using JQueryMobile's Datebox plugin. Its simply an awesome tool and I use it even for date conversion.

Now the problem is to show the Week Number in the date picker along with the Month calender that shows up.

Is there any way to do it in Datbox or anyother plugin available for it?

Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/api/dateformat.html (Might Implement Options) => > The ISO 8601 week number (see NOTES) of the current year as a decimal number, range 01 to 53, where week 1 is the first week that has at least 4 days in the new year. See also %U

Comment: It appear this is not implemented, see this link, under 'Might Implement options': http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/api/dateformat.html

Comment: ohhh okiez.. dat makes sense now.. thanks for the reply @RoryMcCrossan

Do you know anyother plugin dat can do this job?

Comment: hmm.. do you know any other plugin dat shows week number??

Comment: Not specifically, although here's a page which extends Date to have a `getWeek()` method: http://tech-hacks.net/tech/19/get-the-weeknumber-with-javascript/. Hoepfully it's helpful to you.

Comment: Yeah that'll be awesome. Please put your comment as answer if you can I can mark it as answer. I don't think I"m gonna get any better answer than this.

Comment: Hmm - just saw this question - and the bit from tech-hacks that include how to do it - I'll add it within a few days to the main plugin - I'm way, way behind on feature requests.

Comment: Thanks @J.T.Sage Glad to have the comment from the legend himself :) waiting for the new build. Thanks again.

Comment: fwiw - are you looking to *return* the week number, or have it as a separate column along with the dates? (obviously, the first one will defiantly be implemented, but I can see the argument for having the other option available as well)

Comment: 2nd one is the most desired feature as of now. ie to show the week number in another column. First one is also will be an awesome feature though we can write separate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry it took so long, but here ya go:

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/mode/calbox.html (2nd demo)

I believe that is what you are looking for - let me know if it works out.

Comment: This is exactly wot I wanted. Thanks alot :)